# Inline code (backticked) looks different in lists

Tags: bug, markdown, inline-code

Is it supposed to look differently in a list?

Some examples:

`keyword`

---

`keyword`

- `keyword` ← this looks weird

---

1. `keyword`

   - `keyword` ← and this

---

1. `keyword`
2. `keyword`

---

1. `keyword` ← this too